# show preview of selected images before submitting (php) using only javascript

Tags: javascript

i am stuck trying to show preview of user selected images ( show multiple images ) in my page , but what i get is that when i select new image it replace the old one

```js
function showImage() {
  var fr=new FileReader();
  var body = document.getElementById('b');
  // when image is loaded, set the src of the image where you want to display it
   fr.onload = function(e) { 
    body.innerHTML+='<img src='+this.result+'>';
   };
  
  src.addEventListener("change",function() {
   // fill fr with image data
      fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);
  });
 }
 showImage();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>img</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  img{
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body id="b">
<input type="file" id="src" style="display: block;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

You should add multiple as attribute to your input.

```js
function showImage() {
  var fr=new FileReader();
  var body = document.getElementById('b');
  // when image is loaded, set the src of the image where you want to display it
   fr.onload = function(e) { 
    $('body').append('<img src='+this.result+'>');
   };
  
  src.addEventListener("change",function() {
   // fill fr with image data
      fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);
  });
 }
 showImage();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <title>img</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  img{
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body id="b">
<input type="file" id="src" style="display: block;" multiple>
</body>
```